# CMake-C++ Modules Minimal example

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20, c++-modules

Since the [cmake 3.28 release](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.28.html) and following their [first example](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-the-experiment-is-over/) I'm trying to create a minimal example with [Module Partitions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules)

This is my current minimal example and `CMakeFile.txt`

```cpp
// Point2D.cxx
export module Math:Point2D;

export
struct Point2D
{
    int x_{};
    int y_{};
};
```

```cpp
// Math.cxx
export module Math;
export import :Point2D;
```

```
// CMakeFile.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(modules VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES OFF)

add_library(Math-Point2D)
target_sources(Math-Point2D PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/Point2D.cxx
)

add_library(Math)
target_link_libraries(Math PRIVATE Math-Point2D)
target_sources(Math PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/Math.cxx
)

add_executable(modules main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(modules PRIVATE Math)
```

I've also tried to create just one library and inserting both files in the same lib, as follows:

```
add_library(Math)
target_sources(Math PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/Point2D.cxx
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Math/Math.cxx
)
```

But none seems to work, I've tried with `Makefile`, and with `make` seems to (just compiling both files separately and linking all at the end...)

Any idea?
I don't see any logic of creating Modules if I cannot create partitions...

Comment: What do you mean by "none seems to work"? What error did you get?

Comment: Do you have  one of the required compilers installed?

Comment: "just compiling both files separately and linking all at the end" -- that's exactly what is _supposed_ to happen.

Comment: @cpplearner Math.cxx.o.modmap -o CMakeFiles/Math.dir/src/Math/Math.cxx.o -c /home/pablo/modules/src/Math/Math.cxx
[build] /home/pablo/modules/src/Math/Math.cxx:3:16: fatal error: module 'Math:Point2D' not found this is my error

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I do, I'm try with Clang 16.0.6

Answer (score 0):

You set `CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES` to `OFF`.

This *disables* dependency scanning for your `main.cpp`, so module dependencies from `import`s in that file will not be taken into account as build dependencies.

Don't set that option.

Also, you mention that you are using `Makefiles`. CMake's Module support does not work with the Makefiles generator, as is clearly stated [in the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-cxxmodules.7.html):

> The list of generators which support scanning sources for C++ modules include:
>
> - Ninja
> - Ninja Multi-Config
> - Visual Studio 17 2022

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding (my fault), actually I'm generating the project with CMake/Ninja to build, but I've tried this same example with a plain Makefile (on a different project) and it works.